# How do I tell preg_match_all() to possibly expect, but ignore certain strings?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I'm certainly missing something obvious,because this is terribly simple, but here's the problem I'm running into.

In scraping a web site I'm pulling some links that have a format similar to:

```
<a href="/test.php?var1=123&var2=456&var3=789">SomeString</a>
```

Though on occasion some of the links look like:

```
<a href="/test.php?var1=123&var2=456&var3=789" title="sometitle">SomeString</a>
```

Using a regular expression like the following works, but it adds a match that I don't want:

```
'/<a href=\"/test.php\?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\"(^.*?)>(^.*?)<\/a>'
```

So obviously I'm getting a match I don't want here, but it does take into account the possibly of the "title" variable showing up.  Is there a way to tell preg_match_all() "There may be something here, but you should ignore it"  or if it finds it, it matches it?

Thanks.

Edit, because it wasn't clear:

In my original example I want to find out what var1, var2, var3 are equal to, as well as the text between  and  (SomeString in my example).  If I'm going through a page with a lot of results, occasionally one will have "title=" within the string, which will throw my regex off.  So I want to tell it "this may be here, but don't match, just ignore it".

Comment: If you don't want to work with extremely complicated regex, you may find it simpler to simply replace all instances of `title="sometitle"` with `""` (nothing).

Comment: Can you tell what exactly you wanna do with regex? you don't wanna get numeric results?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.


Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Comment: @AndyLester: `parse_url` doesn't work with relative urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bearing in mind that parsing html with regex is not the best way, you can use this more portable solution:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~
(?:                       # open a non-capturing group
    <a\s                  # begining of the a tag
    (?:                   # open a non capturing group
        [^h>]+            # all characters but "h" and "<" one or more times
      |                   # OR
        \Bh+              # one or more "h" not preceded by a word bundary
      |                   # OR
        h(?!ref\b)        # "h" not followed by "ref"
    )*+                   # repeat the group zero or more times
    href\s*=\s*"[^?]+\?   # href with the begining of the link until the "?"
    \K                    # reset all the match (this part is not needed)
  |                       # OR
    \G(?!\A)              # a contiguous match
)                         # close the non-capturing group
(?:                       # open a non capturing group
    (?<key>[^=&]++)       # take the key
    =                     # until the "="
    (?<value>[^&"]++)     # take the value
    (?: & | (?=") )       # a "&" or followed by a double quote
  |                       # OR
    "[^>]*>               # a double quote and the end of the opening tag
    (?<content>           # open the content named capturing group
        (?:               # open a non capturing group
            [^<]+         # all characters but "<" one or more times
          |               # OR
            <(?!/a\b)     # a "<" not followed by "/a" (the closing a tag)
        )*+               # repeat the group zero or more times
    )                     # close the named capturing group
    </a>                  # the closing tag (can be removed)
)                         # close the non-capturing group
~xi
LOD;
```

This pattern allows several things:

- it doesn't care about the order or number of attributes in the a tag
- it doesn't care about the number of key/value pairs (it takes all)
- it ignores a tags without key/value inside the url
- it allows spaces here ( `href =   "` )
- it supports html tags inside the content part

But it's a little more difficult to extract results:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

foreach($matches['key'] as $k => $v) {
    if (empty($v)) {
        $result[] = array('values'  => $keyval,
                          'content' => $matches['content'][$k]);
        unset($keyval);
    } else {
        $keyval[] = array($v => $matches['value'][$k]);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

---

#### The DOM way

The main interest of this way is that a DOM parser has a similar behaviour than a browser (which is a parser too), in the sense that it doesn't care about number or position of attributes, simple, double or no quotes, and the type of content between tags.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($yourhtml);
$linkNodeList = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($linkNodeList as $linkNode) {
    if (preg_match('~var1=(?<var1>\d+)&var2=(?<var2>\d+)&var3=(?<var3>\d+)~i',
                   $linkNode->getAttribute('href'), $match)) {
       foreach($match as $k => &$v) {
           if (is_numeric($k)) unset($v);
       }
       // take the content between "a" tags
       $content= ''; 
       $children = $linkNode->childNodes; 
       foreach ($children as $child) { 
           $content .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
       }

       $result[] = array('values' => $match, 'content' => $content);
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will:

- find the proper href value
- allow the href value to be single or double quoted, or not quoted at all
- extract the query string values for var1, var2, and var3
- avoid any other attributes in the anchor tag
- allow attriubtes to appear in any order
- avoid difficult edge cases which makes matching html text difficult with a regular expression

`<a\b(?=\s)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref=(['"]?)\/test.php\?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\1(?:\s|\/>|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>(.*?)<\/a>`

[image]

## Example

[Live demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/ZJEwB9m7HC)

**Sample Text**

Note the rather difficult edge case in the mouseover attibute

`<a onmouseover=' href="/test.php?var1=666&var2=666&var3=666" ; if ( 6 > a ) { funRotate(href) } ; ' href="/test.php?var1=123&var2=456&var3=789" title="sometitle">SomeString</a>`

**Matches**

Group 0 gets the entire tag from open to close 
Group 1 gets the quote, which is then used internally to ensure the proper quote is used to close the href value
Group 2-4 gets the values from the var1, var2, and var3
Group 5 gets the inner string between the `<a...>`...`</a>`

```
[0][0] = <a onmouseover=' href="/test.php?var1=666&var2=666&var3=666" ; if ( 6 > a ) { funRotate(href) } ; ' href="/test.php?var1=123&var2=456&var3=789" title="sometitle">SomeString</a>
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = 123
[0][3] = 456
[0][4] = 789
[0][5] = SomeString
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `?` or `*` characters. `?` is called non-greedy, but I think of it simply as being "optional". `*` matches "zero or more".

Your regex should be changed to

```
'/<a href=\"/test.php?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\"(^.*?)?>(^.*?)<\/a>'
                                                                       ^
```

OR

```
'/<a href=\"/test.php?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\"(^.*?)*>(^.*?)<\/a>'
                                                                       ^
```

And if you don't want to group the bit about `title="something"`, then you can avoid capturing by using `(?:)` in your regexes. so

```
'/<a href=\"/test.php?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\"(?:^.*?)*>(^.*?)<\/a>'
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This almost worked, with a small caveat. 

(?:.*?) worked perfectly, and the string was found on the offending line, and ignored by preg_match_all.  Both (?:^.*?) and (?:^.*?)* failed.

Comment: Sorry, return adds comment instead of going to new line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
^<a\shref=\"\/test.php\?var1=([0-9]+)&var2=([0-9]+)&var3=([0-9]+)\"(?:.*?)>(.*)?<\/a>$
```

The question mark should be escaped in the regex...otherwise it matches

```
 <a href="/test.phvar1=123&var2=456&var3=789">SomeString</a>
```